# How to place My Sites inside another site's URL but still keep them logically isolated?

Tags: 2013, site-collection, my-site, web-application, url

I'm setting up SharePoint 2013 as a company intranet site, and we want to implement My Sites; I know the best practices call for placing them in their own web application and content DB, but we'd really like to avoid using a different host name or port, and just keep their URL inside the main site.

What we want:

http://intranet.company.com - main company Intranet portal
http://intranet.company.com/mysites - My Sites

I know this is possible by creating a managed path and two site collections, but I can't seem to find a way to separate the two web applications, their application pools and their content DBs.

Is it possible to achieve this URL scheme but still keep these components logically isolated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with two separate web applications.  A SharePoint web app cannot run under the site structure of another.

The best you could do here is put the My Site host in its own site collection and put that site collection in a different content database than the rest of the web application.

Comment: Exactly what I was fearing... fine. How can I put the site contents in a specific content DB? I can't find any option for selecting that when creating the site collection.

Comment: First, create a new content database for your web app (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825314.aspx).  Once you have the additional content database, use the Move-SPSite cmdlet to move your site collection to the new databases (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915.aspx).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looks like providing an option to select the DB from the beginning would have been really too much...

Comment: In this instance, you might use the first content database as the one that is used by personal sites, etc.  And then move the main site collection to a new content database.  That way when new personal sites get added, they automatically go in the correct database.

Comment: Last I remember content databases are "load balanced" in that Sharepoint will distribute the content databases evenly to all databases that are in the Ready/Online state. To deal with that, I had to periodically run stsadm command to move My Sites into our desired My Site content database.

Comment: Why not use Host Named Site Collections for best practice. When creating a new Site Collection you have to do it by Powershell. You can provide a database name within your script, and when the database is not yet created, it will be created.

Answer (score 1):

in CA under Application Management->Manage Content Databases
click on the Databases which do not host the MySite Sitecollection and reduce the number of Sitecollections to the absolut necessary amount.
Example:
I plan to use 2 SCs in PortalDB, 3 SCs in TeamDB. I set the Max Number of SCs on those DBs to 2 and 3 and create my SCs in them. Now the Maximum of those DBs is reached and no new SCs can be created in them.

The MySite DB is still able to hold my 5000 SCs and every user who creates his MySite will create this through the SharePoint DB Loadbalancing in the MySite DB.